# What is the relation between "tag number in .proto file of a field" and "number (used in parsing through switch case) in the generated code"?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Consider the following proto file.

```
syntax="proto3";
message MessageWithInternalMessage { 
    string F1 = 1;
    _S1 s2 = 5;
    message _S1 {
        string C1 = 1;
        string C2 = 2;
    }
}
```

When we generate the code for it. The parsing is done using the readTag() and then a switch statement to set the corresponding field. Or Consider the following snippet.

```
 while (!done) {
    int tag = input.readTag();
    switch (tag) {
        case 0:
            done = true;
            break;
        default: {
            if (!parseUnknownFieldProto3(input, unknownFields, extensionRegistry, tag)) {
                done = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 10: {
            java.lang.String s = input.readStringRequireUtf8();
            f1_ = s;
            break;
        }
        case 42: {
            Test.InternalMessageWithSeciton._S1.Builder subBuilder = null;
            if (s2_ != null) {
            subBuilder = s2_.toBuilder();
            }
            s2_ = input.readMessage(Test.InternalMessageWithSeciton._S1.parser(), extensionRegistry);
            if (subBuilder != null) {
                subBuilder.mergeFrom(s2_);
                s2_ = subBuilder.buildPartial();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is what is the relation between the 
"tag 1 for the field F1" in proto file to "case 10 in generated code" and 
"tag 5 for the field s2" to "case 42 in generated code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoded format for headers is basically:

```
header = (fieldNumber << 3) | expectedWireType;
```

Where the "wire type" is an integer between 0 and 7.

- 0 = varint - base-128 encoded integer with continuation bit
- 1 = 64 bit (integer or floating point)
- 2 = length-prefixed data - a varint of the number of bytes followed by that many  bytes (strings, BLOBs, sub-messages, packed arrays)
- 5 = 32 bit (integer or floating point)

So field 1 as a string is (1 << 3) | 2 which is binary 1010, or: 10. Field 5 as a sub-message is likewise (5 << 3) | 2, or: 42

Comment: Gravel 
as you said "expectedWireType"  can take values between 0 and 7. In what cases should I use 3,4,6,7?

Comment: @Ran 3 and 4 are start/end group markers - groups are largely deprecated and you won't need them usually. 6 and 7 are reserved for future use.

Comment: when we code generate for a repeated packable data type the code generated as two tags in the generated code.
For ex if I code generate for **repeated int32 f = 1;**
the generated code will be similar to 
 **case 8: {
  }
    case 10: {
  }**
This is to make data written is compatible wth packed true and packed false.
I want to know the logic in generating the 8 and 10 from the tag 1.
**8 is 1000 // 1 is tag and 000 is wire format number**

and **10 is 1010 // 1 is tag and 010 is wire format number.**

**My qn is why the same int32 has two wire format nums? and what is the logic**

Comment: @Ran fields headers are: `header = (fieldNumber << 3) | wireType` - the  `fieldNumber` is the `1` in `f=1`; the `wireType` is the protocol encoding format, a 3-bit number (so: 0-7, although not all are used). Header 8 is "field 1, wire-type 0 (varint)"; header 10 is "field 1, wire-type 2 (length-prefixed)". In the case of repeated **primitives**, length-prefixed is how "packed" arrays/lists/etc are sent; so: instead of saying "{header 8}{1st value}{header 8}{2nd value}{header 8}{3rd value}" it sends "{header 10}{length=6}{1st value}{2nd value}{3rd value}" which can save a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: @Ran especially for large arrays; obviously it isn't so clear when there are only 3 values, but when there are 300: that will be "{header size}{length size}{size of 300 values}" (where the length size will typically be just a few bytes) vs 300x "{header size}{value size}"